# Infinite limit in all points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Do there exist a Banach space (possibly nonseparable) $X$ and a mapping $F: X\to X$ such that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \|F(x)\| = +\infty \quad \forall a\in X\quad?
$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem $\;$ 

Comment: Cross-post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384964/infinite-limit-in-all-points/385249

Comment: (more details on Ricky Demer's hint: Sublevel sets of ||F|| can't be all nowhere dense subsets of X. )